# How do I install Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, under a volume licensing agreement?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I log on to the volume licensing centre, I cannot see a download for Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition (only TFS 2017). I understand that the licensing model has changed, so do I instead need to go "somewhere else" and allocate a licence to each of my users?

Comment: Do you have a VL for retail Visual Studio, or for a MSDN/Visual Studio Subscription? In the latter case nothing has changed, the users allocated subscriptions authorise their install by logging into their subscription (and can download from my.visualstudio.com. (Names have changed, but not the process.)

Comment: Believe it's VL for retail Visual Studio Enterprise (at least that's how it was for 2015)

Comment: I'm having the same issue - no MSDN subsription, however we do have a volume licence and software assurance.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Visual Studio Licensing, March 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Visual-Studio-2017-Licensing-Whitepaper-March-2017.pdf), page 7, seems to say that Enterprise Volume License Subscription will not include Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: From my reading of that, we should still be able to get Visual Studio Enterprise Subscriptions via volume licensing, but it's not clear *how*?